# The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access) in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftp-client, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to upload an image to FTP server. But I'm getting an error

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Here is my code:

```
public void Upload(string fileName, string base64, string path)
{
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    var uri = new Uri($"ftp://{Host}/{path}/{fileName}");
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.UsePassive = false;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    request.UseBinary = true;
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
    }

    using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response != null)
            response.Close();
    }
}
```

My `Host` is something like this: `localhost:port-number`.
The path is a folder named `Images`.
So I want to save the image at `localhost:port-number/Images` but I am getting that error.
When I open the FTP point from the browser, it works fine and I can see the content. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, setting [`FtpWebRequest.UsePassive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive) to `false` is a bad idea. Stick with the default `true`, unless you have a good reason to use the active mode.

Read *my* article on the [FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) to understand why.

---

The server probably returns a relevant error message with the `550` code. But the FTP implementation in .NET framework translates all FTP status codes to its own (localized) message. Particularly code 550 is translated to *"File unavailable"*. That, in some cases (like probably this one), hides away the real problem.